# How to make results above content? Z-index search field issue

Tags: search, z-index

This code appears in a siteorigin layout builder in the header widget area. There are four elements, and #4 is a search box. When you type anything into the box, the suggested results appear **under** the content below.

I tried a z-index on the header, the widget, assigning a special class to the widget with a high z-index, and got nothing.

https://www.carmelchamber.org/

Any thoughts please, because I'm stuck.

Thank you!

Luke

Answer (score 0):

This was a tough one to locate. Please, try adding to Custom CSS:

```
.panel-row-style,
.elementor-section {
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
}
```

That's to override a rule in the parent stylesheet.